# Are there any specific laws and consequences for claiming to be God?

Tags: halacha, theology, mitzvah

Is there a specific command to not equate yourself to God?  For instance, someone says, "I am God."  This someone is a believer and a member of the Jewish faith, not an unbeliever.  I'm curious if Moses addressed this at all.

Comment: @AdamHeeg Since Judaism believes God doesn't have a physical form, a person who claims to be God is probably just a blithering idiot. Don't pay much attention to them. They are probably too ignorant of traditional Jewish belief or too mentally unstable to warrant punishment.

Comment: Double AA thank you for the advice.  However, I'd like to know if there is anything specific written about this topic.  I came here to ask since my research was not able to turn anything up so far.

Comment: The only person who had such a claim made about him is called the "founder" of a nonJewish religion. If someone actually did make such a claim, then he would not be `a believer and a member of the Jewish faith`. The only reference in the Torah would be the reference in Deuteronymy to a false prophet.

Comment: @AdamHeeg You are unlikely to find many references. Judaism (like most intellectual pursuits) doesn't spend much time listing all the stupid things someone could possibly claim.

Comment: Can I equate myself to the infinite? There is a difference between imagination and philosophy. If I write a book, what is happening in the book is the fact of G_d for the fictional persons. So I equate myself to G_d. But the reality is not my book and I don't equate myself to G_d. In some psychotic states I can have delusions as being G_d, after a good treatment it will go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The great Torah scholar and codifier of Jewish law, the [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) (R Moshe ben Maimon, 1135-1204) compiled what he calls the **"Thirteen Fundamental Principles of the Jewish faith"**, as derived from the Torah. They were to him "the fundamental truths of our religion and its very foundations." (from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/332555/jewish/Maimonides-13-Principles-of-Faith.htm)).

Some have challenged to what extent everyone always agreed with all of them, but to a large extent they represent the foundational beliefs of every traditional Jew.

The first four principles are

1. Belief in the existence of the Creator, who is perfect in every manner of existence and is the primary cause of all that exists
2. The belief in God's absolute and unparalleled unity
3. The belief in God's non-corporeality, nor that He will be affected by any physical occurrences, such as movement, or rest, or dwelling
4. The belief in God's eternity

**These principles are completely and fundamentally opposed to the idea that any man could be God. As such any person claiming to be God could not be called a believing Jew in the traditional sense.**

Comment: Very fantastic answer and I hope to find some time to review your reference for other topics as well.  Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

given the many verses which contradict you such as "no man can see me and live" (Ex.33:20) you will probably be seen as a lunatic at best and perhaps get lashes by the Rabbis for a start.